# How its like to fly an big back airliner with an sidestick ? How sensitive is the "joystick"?

Tags: aircraft-design, flight-controls, airbus

Edited because it was "unclear" 
Now Airbus uses sidesticks as control inputs 
It looks weird for me because a tiny movement in the joystick would make a big movement and "joystick sensivity" would be extremely big and these things aren't needed for "Baby Got Back" airliners 
So Why Airbus uses a joystick that has great "joystick sensitivy" ? Shouldn't sidesticks be reserved for tiny airplanes like Cirrus and F4E Phantom II ? (Whenever I see an regular F4 I laugh my ass off, Who would design a FIGHTER Bomber without an cannon ?)

Comment: "Is it comfortable?" is opinion-based. Please do not look for opinions here, you might want to try our chat for those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sidestick vs. Yoke](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23388/sidestick-vs-yoke)

Comment: As long as the control surfaces are hydraulically actuated (so you don't need to exert a large force on the cockpit controls), what does it matter what the size of the aircraft is? The size of the pilot seems to matter more.

Comment: This question sounds awfully like, "joysticks are too sensitive, and yokes are better. Am I right?"  By stating that joysticks have great sensitivity and joysticks "aren't needed" for larger airliners you're presuming the answer in your question, forcing us to either tell you you've completely misunderstood things or just say, "yes, you're right".  A better question would just ask why side sticks exist or whether they're too sensitive, although the latter would be very opinion-based.  Do you want to learn or do you just want someone to agree or argue with you?

Comment: I Just want to know how sensitive sidesticks are

Comment: A side stick that can deflect 40 degrees is exactly as sensitive as a stick that can deflect 40 degrees.

Answer (score 6):

Pilots fly big back airliners with a side stick very well. They also fly F-16s with a side stick very well.

As Airbus put it in an article in Flight Magazine: If side sticks were the norm and it would be proposed putting a big stick in front of the seat, making it hard to get in and partially blocking view of the instruments, pilots would protest".

All airliners have hydraulically deflected control surfaces, they don't need to physically overcome the airforces anymore. Their control stick can take any convenient shape,

Comment: Why not make an glass yoke ? (A super strong glass that wont crack in landing)

Comment: @JonathanIrons Answer that question yourself by holding a clear glass bottle between your face and your screen while writing a reply to this comment.

Comment: "*Why not make an glass yoke?*": What problem is it supposed to solve?